# Kendo UI Scheduler - Check is date in recurrence rule

Tags: date, kendo-ui, scheduler, rule, recurrence

I have recurrence rule(for example like "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE"), start date and end date. 
Where can I find method or function to check is current date enters in my rule or not?

For example if I have:
Start date: 01.02.2017 
End date: 03.02.2017 
Recurrence rule: "FREQ=DAILY;NTERVAL=5"

So, in this case date 4.02.2017 not enters in this rule, but date 5.02.2017 enters in this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the scheduler's `occurrencesInRange` method like this:

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
var events = scheduler.occurrencesInRange(
  new Date("2017-02-05"), // The date you want to check at 0:00 am
  new Date("2017-02-06")  // The same date + 24 hours
);
```

You'll get a list of recurring dates in that date. If the array isn't empty then the start date you supplied the above method has an occurance in it.